# Adding new sites to Multisite won't register in Dashboard

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I am having a real issue here that I can't seem to find an answer to. I am using Plesk, and have setup a new subscription. I have all of the proper settings, using FastCGI, ownership of files, etc. On a fresh install of wordpress and allowing multisite I cannot seem to create a new site and have it show up in the admin dashboard, or under My Sites dropdown. However, they do actually register in the database and I can access them through the Sites tab. I am completely lost here as to why this is possible.

In addition, when I try to activate my Gravity Forms Plugin and click on the Register settings link, I get the "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

If anyone can give me some insite here I would truly appreciate it so I can stop banging my head against a wall.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your vhost and check for  'allow override=All ... If this is also a new server it might explain the problems

See my post here on [how to check your apache config](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57652/permalinks-to-custom-does-not-work-out-of-box/58431#58431)

You might also like to check that the folder permissions are set correctly for WordPress ie `www-data` (the Apache user on Ubunutu servers) needs to have own/read/write everything in your WordPRess directory or be in the same group (this is important for plugins to run)